# Is there a standard way to use a std::basic_string with a stack allocated buffer greater in size than SSO, rather than heap

Tags: c++, string, heap-memory, allocator, stack-memory

Is there an existing standard way for `std::basic_string` to use stack allocated space to do string operations, rather than heap allocated space- and then heap space if a certain size limit is exceeded.

And as clarification to one of the comments, I know in advance about the size of the strings I'm going to be dealing with, so I would like to control the size of the stack allocated buffer.

I know I could write a custom allocator to do this, but was wondering if this exists in std, or some other library without a billion dependencies.

It might look something like:

```
std::basic_string<
   char, 
   std::char_traits<char>, 
   my_awesome_stack_then_heap_allocator<char, 255>
> my_string;
```

Ideas?

Comment: What is the use-case? What is the actual and real problem this is supposed to solve? And remember that the stack is usually a very limited resource, while the heap usually isn't.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Use case and actual real problem are irrelevant to my question.  You are correct the stack is a limited resource.

Comment: Please read about [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you ask about your *real* problem, we might help you with that instead. Right now this question seems more like a solution in search of a (currently non-existing) problem.

Comment: Most implementations of `std::string` do exactly that. It's called "small string optimization". But you don't get to control the size of the buffer.

Comment: Use a stack `char buffer[255]` and `std::string_view`, perhaps.

Comment: The `std::string` class isn't a template, it's a template specialization. The template is `std::basic_string`.

Comment: @forthe ah, oops, you are correct, will fix

Comment: @PeteBecker Interesting.  I didn't know this.  Yeah, I would like to control the stack buffer size.  Let me adjust the question.

Comment: _I would like to control the stack buffer size_   -  Which brings us back to the question @Someprogrammerdude asked - why do you want to control the buffer size?  It's likely the question isn't irrelevant.  There may be answers that allow control of stack buffer size but **don't** address your need.  There may be answers that address your need but **don't** control stack buffer size.  Without knowing more about **why** you want to control stack buffer size it is difficult to construct a useful answer.

Comment: @FrankBoyne My question is my question.  Nothing more, nothing less.  Perhaps I don't even have a use for the answer.  There is no other question in this question, besides the question I'm asking.  If you ask me what 2+2 is, I will not ask you why.

Comment: It may not feel like it at the moment but I'm really not trying to be difficult.

Comment: Can you quantify "some other library without a billion dependencies"?